# passing a file as argument to main function in netbeans c++

Tags: c++, netbeans

i go to projetctproperties -> run -> arguments  i pass a filename but where do i have to place the file?

Answer (score 0):

Into the working directory. You can set it in the next field in the same window.

Without setting the working directory you should use the base folder of the project.